# Transforming corresponding Start-Stop Time in rows to columns

Tags: sql, pivot, transformation

I have a table in this format:

| User | Time | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 2021-12-24 14:00:00 | connect |
| User 2 | 2021-12-24 14:05:23 | connect |
| User 2 | 2021-12-24 14:10:11 | disconnect |
| User 2 | 2021-12-24 14:10:17 | connect |
| User 1 | 2021-12-24 19:35:22 | disconnect |
| User 2 | 2021-12-25 01:10:40 | disconnect |

I'd like to have a table with connect & disconnect as columns, one row for each session from connect to next disconnect per user

| User | connect | disconnect |
| --- | --- | --- |
| User 1 | 2021-12-24 14:00:00 | 2021-12-24 19:35:22 |
| User 2 | 2021-12-24 14:05:23 | 2021-12-24 14:10:11 |
| User 2 | 2021-12-24 14:10:17 | 2021-12-25 01:10:40 |

I could create this on MySQL, MariaDB or MSSQL, depending on where it's easier to do. Is it possible to do as a view? Great addon, but not absolutely necessary: column "duration" that shows the duration of each session from connect to disconnect.

If easier, connect/disconnect times could be (mili)seconds from 1970/1/1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution, it should work in most RDBMS, being careful to correctly delimit column names that clash with reserved words.

First you need to pair up the connects/disconnects, this can be done by numbering the rows and then duplicating every-other number using a modulo, then using conditional aggregation:

```
with rn as (
  select *, 
    Row_Number() over(partition by user order by time) rn
  from t
), gp as (
  select *, 
    case when rn %2=0 then
      Lag(rn) over(partition by user order by rn) 
    else rn end gp
  from rn
)
select 
    [user], 
    Max(case when status = 'connect' then time end) Connect,
    Max(case when status = 'disconnect' then time end) Disconnect
from gp
group by user, gp
```

Answer (score 0):

The *Conditional Aggregation* can be used after applying **`ROW_NUMBER()`** window function if your available databases' versions are **8.0+**, **10.2+** and **2005** for **MySQL**, **MariaDB** and **SQL Server** respectively such as

```sql
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user,status ORDER BY time) AS rn,
       t.*
  FROM t     
)
SELECT User, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'connect' THEN time END) AS connect,
       MAX(CASE WHEN status = 'disconnect' THEN time END) AS disconnect
  FROM t2
 GROUP BY user, rn
 ORDER BY user, rn
```

where

- the dataset is grouped by **`user`** and **`status`** columns while
  sorted by **`time`** column
- **`user`**, which's a *reserved keyword*, must be replaced by **`[user]`** as a column name for **SQL Server** DB

<kbd>[Demo for MySQL/MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=41cf01345c2ed0d78094255d79788001)</kbd>

<kbd>[Demo for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97cb75729ddd04ee8c61d97e932026fe)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

According to the general way of thinking, you just need to sort records arranged by user and time according to user, and, in each group, get the disconnect time from each even numbered row. SQL uses a roundabout method to do this. The method uses window function and specifically creates “row numbers” to achieve the goal. A convenient alternative is to import data out of database and handle it in Python or SPL. SPL, the open-source Java package, is easier to be integrated into a Java program and generate more concise code. It can accomplish the task with only two lines of code:

```
data=MYSQL.query("SELECT USER,TIME FROM t ORDER BY USER,TIME")
result=data.new(USER,TIME:CONNECT,if(#%2==1,TIME[+1]):DISCONNECT).select(DISCONNECT)
```